# jquery each json variable bug

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a strange bug. When I try to run my code:

```
var firstJson;
$.getJSON(site_url+"/more/sector_by_city/"+id+"?"+Math.random(), function( json ) { 
    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
        firstJson = 9;  
    });
}); 
alert(firstJson);
```

The alert I get is: `"undefined"`.

Why did I get this instead of getting `9`?

What am I missing here?

(the each loop runs without issue and there are values in the JSON)
At the end, `9` changes to some other value.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable doesnt have a value when `alert` is called. You'll have to wait `getJSON` is over, using `done()`.

```
var firstJson;
$.getJSON(site_url+"/more/sector_by_city/"+id+"?"+Math.random(), function( json ) { 
    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
        firstJson = 9;  
    });
}).done(function() {
   alert(firstJson);
});
```

References:

1. [`done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)
2. [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 6):

Async functions my friend. Your alert is being called before your `.getJSON` request has been finished. You'll need to use a callback function to get the correct alert.

Answer (score 4):

Because when you call `alert(firstJson)` the asynchronous `$.getJSON` call has not yet completed, so `firstJson` has no value associated with it. If you move your alert into the `$.each` function or after the `$.each`, and at the end of `$.getJSON`, it will have a value.